# How to return empty row from sql function if no record is found

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL function

```
ALTER FUNCTION FunctionTEST (@itemID bigint) RETURNS table AS RETURN 
(
  (SELECT top 1 Pic_Path from PictureDetails WHERE PictureDetails.Item_ID = @itemID)
)
```

This function will return top row if found against the parameter specified. I want this function to return empty row if no record is found against the Parameter. I think it should be a simple task but i am not familiar with SQL function. Below is the actual query which i am using to call the function.

```
SELECT
NewClientTB.FirstName, NewClientTB.LastName, NewClientTB.EMail, NewClientTB.ContactNo,

ADDetails.AD_ID, ADDetails.AD_EXactAddress, 
ADDetails.AD_PostingTime, ADDetails.AD_Description, ADDetails.AD_Title,

ItemDetails.Item_ID, ItemDetails.Item_Price,

Regions.R_Description,

Cities.C_Name,

GCategories.GC_Description,

SCategories.SC_Description,
PictureDetails.Pic_Path

FROM NewClientTB, ADDetails,ItemDetails, Regions, Cities, GCategories, 
SCategories,     PictureDetails
WHERE FREETEXT (ADDetails.AD_Title, 'selling')
 AND FREETEXT (ADDetails.AD_Description, 'selling')
AND ADDetails.AD_PosterID = NewClientTB.UserID
AND ADDetails.AD_ID = ItemDetails.AD_ID
AND Regions.R_ID = ADDetails.AD_Region
AND Cities.R_ID = ADDetails.AD_Region AND Cities.C_ID = ADDetails.AD_City

AND ItemDetails.Item_GCategory = GCategories.GC_ID
AND ItemDetails.Item_SCategory = SCategories.SC_ID AND ItemDetails.Item_GCategory = 
SCategories.GC_ID
AND PictureDetails.Pic_Path =  (select * from dbo.FunctionTEST(ADDetails.AD_ID))
```

Comment: Why do you want it to return an empty row?  As written, it returns a table with no rows, which makes sense.  Given that you are only returning at most one value, are you sure you want a table-valued function and not a scalar function?

Comment: I am modifying the above question, please see it a minute later

Comment: What do you mean with empty row? A row with all columns value setted to null? This function return an empty table,you can treat as "empty row" and make sense

Comment: I mean if the item (@itemID) exists but has no Pic_Path against it, then it should return empty row, else the Pic_Path with its data

Comment: @user2599269 . . . The way you are using the function, it doesn't make a difference.  The comparison is going to fail where there is one row with a `NULL` value or no rows at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to return no rows when item exist but has no `Pic_Path`:

```
ALTER FUNCTION FunctionTEST (@itemID bigint)
RETURNS table AS RETURN 
(
    SELECT top 1 Pic_Path
    from PictureDetails
    WHERE PictureDetails.Item_ID = @itemID and Pic_Path is not NULL
)
```

Above function should be called with `cross apply` if you want no row for item without `Pic_Path` in result and with `outer apply` if you wish to inlcude such rows in result:

```
SELECT
    nctb.FirstName, nctb.LastName, nctb.EMail, nctb.ContactNo,
    addet.AD_ID, addet.AD_EXactAddress, addet.AD_PostingTime,
    addet.AD_Description, addet.AD_Title,
    idet.Item_ID, idet.Item_Price,
    r.R_Description,
    c.C_Name,
    gcat.GC_Description,
    scat.SC_Description,
    pdet.Pic_Path
FROM
    NewClientTB nctb
    join ADDetails addet on addet.AD_PosterID = nctb.UserID
    join ItemDetails idet on idet.AD_ID = addet.AD_ID
    join Regions r on r.R_ID = addet.AD_Region
    join Cities c on c.R_ID = addet.AD_Region AND c.C_ID = addet.AD_City
    join GCategories gcat on gcat.GC_ID = idet.Item_GCategory
    join SCategories scat on scat.SC_ID = idet.Item_SCategory
    cross apply dbo.FunctionTEST(addet.AD_ID) ft
    join PictureDetails pdet on pdet.Pic_Path = ft.Pic_Path
WHERE FREETEXT (addet.AD_Title, 'selling') AND FREETEXT (addet.AD_Description, 'selling')
```

Comment: Its giving same output in both way, thank you though for your help

Comment: I think it should work, though little modification will be required to be made in my calling query. Thanks

Comment: Yeah, that seems to be standard way of applying joins which i could not make on myself. Thanks for this useful code